# single context but "Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'xyz' between objects in different contexts

Tags: iphone, exception, nsfetchrequest

i've got one Context and i want to create a relationship between an existing Object in the Context *(Veranstaltung)* and a new one *(Ticket)*.

```
 NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext]; //constructor get the Context from the appDelegate

Ticket *ticket = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Ticket" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Veranstaltung" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"vID == %@", veranstaltung.vID];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
NSError *error = nil;

NSArray *fetchedRequests = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
NSLog(@"FetchedRequests count: %d", fetchedRequests.count);

if(fetchedRequests !=nil)
   [ticket setEvent:fetchedRequests[0]];
```

And while setting the Event, the App crashs.. 
Got anyone an idea? Thank you!

Comment: What is the relationship mentioned in the error? It's not actually `'xyz'`, is it?

Comment: aah everytime i don't mentioned, that this is not "ticket", its "gekauftesTicket", the Inverse of 'Ticket' to 'Veranstaltung'

Comment: @Jonathan How did you solve your problem?

Answer (score -1):

From the error message, Core Data seems to feel that `Ticket` and `Veranstaltung` are in different contexts. Looking at the first few lines of code...

```
[self managedObjectContext]; //constructor get the Context from the appDelegate

Ticket *ticket = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Ticket" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
```

It looks like you left something out on one of these lines, and the result is that `managedObjectContext` on the second line isn't what you think. You probably meant either:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext]; //constructor get the Context from the appDelegate
```

or else:

```
Ticket *ticket = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Ticket" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
```

As it is, that first line doesn't do anything useful, since the result is thrown away. I'd suggest putting the second line after the third and using the `context` local variable from the third line everywhere.

Comment: oh i'm sry i forgot to say, that managedObjectContext is intialized before (i tried to short it up sry)

Comment: So why do you need both `managedObjctContext` and `context` local variables? If that's really what your code looks like, then they both point to the same context. If your real code is different, there's a chance that they point to different contexts and that'd explain the error. Using a single local context pointer for both `ticket` and your fetch requests eliminates the possibility that the contexts are different.

Comment: yes you're right, good point. I replaced the context with managedObjectContext, but this doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Note that you can't create relationships across different data stores. If your tickets are in one store and events in another, that could be the problem. Perhaps it's a poorly worded error message.

Comment: what do you mean with 'stores'? i got one Model with Entity Veranstaltung, Tickets etc.. so first i create some 'Veranstaltung' (Events ;) ) and then i want to buy a Ticket and save this in the same model and context and i want to create a relationship between the ticket and the event